# Knockout - While getting a string I obtain instead [object Object]

Tags: knockout.js

I have to retrieve some data using `jQuery.getJSON` and calling an API. As I have to otbain a list of item froma a database I forced every API, writing some lines in Global.asax, to return objects in Json format and excluding Xml.

But I have this problem when I try to get, through a getJSON, a `string`.
I guess the function is not able to recognise that "simple" string because it's expecting a json format.
If my guess is right, how can I retrieve a string from an api?

This is server-side code, or the api action:

```
    public string Get(string userId, string dateStr)
    {
        //item = get from a database
        return item.Value;
    }
```

And this is the client-side function that calls the above-mentioned api:

```
  function GetValue(ui, ds) {
      var self = this;
      var jsko = jQuery.noConflict();
      var baseUri = "http://localhost:8090/api/";
      self.val= jsko.getJSON(baseUri + "get/day/?userId=" + ui + "&dateStr=" + ds);

      alert(self.val);
  };
```

Note 1: I've reported only the lines of code that are causing the problem.
Note 2: Due to routing setting, the url I'm addressing is right.
Note 3: The `Get()` function is bound to a button click in this way:

```
    <button data-bind="click: GetValue.bind($data, $parent.UserId, $parent.dateStr)">get</button>
```

Comment: Can you post the server and client code that creates this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect a plain text from the server using jQuery ajax, you need to set attribute dataType properly: `dataType: "text"`.
By default getJSON method has next options, expecting json:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

If I understood you problem properly, try to change dataType to "text".